# Keys to Monika's apartment

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In one of the episodes of Friends, everybody gets locked out of Monika's apartment (the episode with the long winded discussion over the differentiation between "got the keys!" and "got the keys?").

Furthermore, when Rachel moves out there is a scene where Rachel gives Monika her key to the apartment back.

How come in the last episode it shows that all six friends each had their own key to the apartment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Years pass between these episodes, so I don't think this can really count as a plot inconsistency.  After everyone is locked out of the apartment, Monica could have made sure everyone had a key so this wouldn't happen again.  Rachel gives back her key as a symbolic gesture when she moves out, but it can easily be explained that she's given another key later because she's always there (along with everyone else) even though she no longer lives there.